# python based azure function programming model V2 (deployed via github actions) is not appearing in the azure function list

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, github-actions

Github action workflow completed successfully and files are deployed to function app.

[image]

But functions are not appearing in the azure function list.

[image]

My expectation is to deploy azure function storage queue trigger with programming model V2 using github actions.

Answer (score 0):

***I created one sample Azure Storage queue trigger with Python v2 Programming model and deployed it via Github actions like below:-***

**My function_app.py code:-**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.queue_trigger(arg_name="azqueue", queue_name="myqueue",
                               connection="valleystrg129_STORAGE") 
def queue_trigger(azqueue: func.QueueMessage):
    logging.info('Python Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azqueue.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**host.json:-**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  }
}
```

**local.settings.json:-**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg129;AccountKey=xxxxxyVIUxxxd0ZrE7BVInRkzDF+AStPI60+Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "valleystrg129_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg129;AccountKey=xxxxyVIUtd15vOnm8wt4xxxxkzDF+AStPI60+Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

[image]

My Function queue trigger got deployed to Function app successfully like below:-

**My github action workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - valleyfunc496

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' 
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.10' 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'valleyfunc496'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_4F433CE262C6430E9690DCA16871A27B }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
```

**Output:-**

[image]