# ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD being removed during remote build and function app doesn't get the new version of code

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am working on azure function with python.

Based on the documentation we are supposed to have below two configuration values when we do remote build on linux machine. Navigate [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies?tabs=linux#remote-build) to see more details on this

```
ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=true
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
```

I am using below command to push the build

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource group name> -n <function app name> --src 
<zipfile> --build-remote true --verbose
```

Below is the warning message I am seeing and no error. Also when I try to see the code of the function app it shows the old code and not the new code I am trying to deploy with remote deploy. Am

```
Removing ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD app setting
```

My zip file has below files

- function_app.py

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="from_vscode_http_trigger")
def from_vscode_http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello again again, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

- host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

- local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats an expected behaviour. According to this [Document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies.md#linux) ***remote builds are not performed when an app has previously been set to run in Run From Package mode.***  Also, According to this [**blog**](https://azureossd.github.io/2023/04/17/troubleshooting-python-deployments-on-appservice-linux/)

> When using  `Azure Pipelines`  or  **`ZipDeploy`**, Oryx is not enabled by default since you are using an  `External builder`. If you prefer to enable App Service Build Service (Oryx) then you need to add a new App Setting  **`SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT`=  `true`**  and redeploy.

> When using `Local Git`, `Bitbucket`, `External Git`, `GitHub Actions`, **Oryx** is enabled by default.

***As, SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true enables the Remote build for App service  Build Service, ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD:true is removed while ZipDeploy***

**First Scenario:-**

I created a new Function app with no zip deployment done earlier and added SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT:true and ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD:true setting to the Function App before deployment. And performed the zip deployment with the cli command. The deployment ran sucessfully and it removed ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD:true setting and kept SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT:true setting only.

**Command:-**

```bash
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g xxxxheshrg98 -n siliconfuncremote  --src "C:\Users\user\Desktop\FunctionV2.zip" --build-remote true --verbose
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Second scenario:-**

I tried deploying the Function without
ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=true and SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true settings and it got deployed as zip with remote build:-

```bash
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g xxxddheshrg98 -n valleyfunc789  --src "C:\Users\user\Desktop\FunctionV2.zip" --build-remote true --verbose
```

**Output:-**

Only ***SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true got added automatically*** and the Function was deployed:-

[image]

[image]

**Third scenario:-**

When I used **Github Actions** for the ***Azure Functions Deployment*** the ***ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD:1*** and ***SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true*** settings were added automatically, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

Refer my SO thread answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76924487/python-based-azure-function-programming-model-v2-deployed-via-github-actions-i/76927879#76927879) for Github Actions Deployment.