Where to find Azure Functionapp deploy errors for python 3.11 in the Azure Portal
I want to move my local python 3.11 project to an Azure Functionapp. Somewhere in the deployment process, an error happens, such as an ModuleNotFoundError. I assume it's because a package that can be installed locally just fine, fails to install on the Azure Functionapp. I can't find the errors in the Azure Portal, so I don't know what is wrong.
I created a basic example app which demonstrates my problem

I looked in Application Insights -> Logs -> traces. It shows that my only HTTP endpoint was found, but not loaded. It does not say why.

The Log stream shows no errors.

I managed to find my errors deep inside the portal, at Diagnose and solve problems -> Availability and Performance -> Functions that are not triggering. Here it shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'somenonexistingmodule'. However, these logs seem to be delayed by at least 15 minutes, so I have to wait 15 minutes after every deploy to figure out what is going wrong.
Is it possible to get any deploy errors straight away? Why doesn't the deploy process throw an error when a function doesn't want to load due to an error?

Have you checked your local python version against the Azure Function runtime version?

Make sure you are using a valid pip module in your function app for deployment, Also, In your code you are just importing a module and not using it anywhere in your Function code. In order to resolve your error, Make sure you include a valid module in your requirements.txt file. Also, Try to run the function locally to fetch the errors.
My Function code:-
I have used pandas as an external module.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import pandas

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

My requirements.txt:-
azure-functions
pandas

Output:-
Click on f5 or fn+f5 to run your function trigger locally or run func host start command in your terminal:-

After Deployment:-

For Logging and Monitoring refer my SO answer1 and SO answer2 to fetch the logs correctly.
You can check the Logs from the Logs section where your Logs are saved in Log analytics workspace:-y
traces



Thank you for your response.
"You are just importing a module and not using it anywhere in your Function code. Make sure you include a valid module". I did this on purpose to trigger the error and demonstrate my problem.
"Try to run the function locally to fetch the errors". As stated, the problem doesn't occur locally. Only on Azure Functions during deployment.
Regarding "SO answer1": As stated, the Apps Insight logs don't show an error, the filesystem logstream doesn't load, the traces logs don't give a specific error.
The HTTP Trigger did not deploy so I can't test it.

To check deployment failure logs, Go to your resource group that contains your Function app and > check Deployments tab here- https://i.imgur.com/fW02i1J.png

The Deployments tab from the resource group only shows a single message saying that an Alert Rule was deployed. There is no message or anything that contains the actual ModuleNotFoundError that I am looking for. https://imgur.com/a/6WX68SM

I decided to forget about Azure and go with AWS. This was a horrible experience. The <appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ website is useless, empty, and broken. The logs are at least 30 minutes delayed. The VSCode Azure tools are broken and can't find any files. Deploying it with Azure Functions Core Tools, I only get "Remote build succeeded!" which is completely incorrect, because I purposefully placed an error in my code! The app insights is useless, the logs are useless... All I want is to see my "ModuleNotFoundError" or "SyntaxError" or whatever is wrong. Horrible experience, never again.

@EmielSteerneman Apologies for the experience, Try to deploy your Function app via github action and check the logs in your github action run - Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76924487/python-based-azure-function-programming-model-v2-deployed-via-github-actions-i/76927879#76927879 Visit your Function app > Deployment Center > Select github and your github repository containing the above function code and click save the workflow will start by itself.

Apologies for the rant, I was highly frustrated. Github Action does not list the runtime errors that I'm presumably having. I do not understand why runtime errors do not show up in my Function App logs. Would you mind having a quick look at my host.json? https://imgur.com/a/TMDmQQY https://github.com/emielsteerneman/TDP/blob/refactor/host.json
